# Are there any limits on field history tracking?

Tags: custom-field, history-tracking, field-history

If I have a record that is updated every 5 minutes, and I have field history enabled on the field changing, will I run into any field history tracking limits?

Ex. Does Salesforce only store X number of changes per record in the field history?

Comment: On top of my head, no, I had for a record which was changing every 10 seconds for 3 months just to test the extent the field history was tracked, It never failed me.

Comment: Field History is built on a standard BigObject, so theoretically it can scale to hundreds of millions of rows or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select certain fields to track and display the field history in the History related list of an object. **The field history data is retained for up to 18 months.**

You can track the field history of custom objects and the following standard objects.
Accounts

1. Articles
2. Assets
3. Campaigns
4. Cases
5. Contacts
6. Contracts
7. Contract
8. line
9. items
10. Entitlements
11. Leads
12. Opportunities
13. Orders
14. Order
15. Products
16. Products
17. Service
18. Contracts
19. Solutions

**More on limitations here**: [Consider the following when working with field history tracking.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/tracking_field_history.htm)

As far as your question is concerned. **No i don't see any such limitations**!